# Understanding Virtual ICU

Tags: icu-intensive-care-unit

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I'll ask it anyway...

I heard of this hospital called Mercy Virtual. It is a virtual ICU. How is this possible? In general, how can telehealth be relied on? More specifically - by definition ICU cases are in a rough spot and can require immediate surgeries etc. How can telehealth be used for them?

Comment: It's the right place to ask but I wish you had read the [help] and learned how to ask questions here first. When your question begins with "I heard about" then you need to give us links to where you heard about it. But before you post your question, you need to google the issue and do some basic homework on your own. We call that prior research and it's a requirement here. I googled Mercy Virtual and it appears you may misunderstand what it is. It's not a virtual ICU, and it doesn't provide services to patients. It provides consulting services to doctors and medical professionals.

Comment: You can get a better idea of what it is by having a look at their [web site's About page](https://www.mercyvirtual.net/about/). There's no reason why experts can't collaborate via the internet.

Comment: @CareyGregory this looked interesting, so I looked it up. Perhaps this is where the OP got the idea of ICU from "houses the nation’s largest single-hub electronic intensive care unit" (From https://www.nashvillemedicalnews.com/world-s-first-virtual-care-center-launched-cms-904). Honestly, I do not understand what that means. Do you?

Comment: @CareyGregory it says here (https://www.mercyvirtual.net/worlds-first-virtual-care-center/) a bit more about the vICU. What I don't understand is how this can work - how can a doctor be effective in an ICU capacity remotely?

Comment: @Burt I agree it's an interesting question.

Comment: Welcome to this site @user17233, very good and interesting question. I'd advice to change the title into a real question such as "How can telehealth be used in ICU?" or "Is telehealth reliable enough for use in ICU?" or maybe your question is more about practical use then reliability so then something like "What are the practical use cases of telehealth in ICU?". Please be more specific. Also adding references to reliable sources that understate (parts of) your question would greatly improve it.